# UI Activity in the POP window in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-popupwindow

I would like to use the popup window for my UI activity. 
Actually, I have a button in my main activity page which on clicked should open like a dialog window.

In that dialogue window, I want to have two other buttons in it  which on clicked should pass some value for every click**(without the window being disappeared)** and if there is no click for defined time (time-out) it should vanish and return to the main activity.

I can do this using "Intent" but i want to implement it with this automatically vanishing dialog window after time-out. How can i do this.? 
please help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: this example may be useful for you to handle popup view.. 

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Answer (score 0):

First declare one global varialbe for `Handler` to update the UI control from `Thread`, like below-

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Now create one `Thread` and use while loop to periodically perform the task using the sleep method of the thread.
Suppose you have `menu_bt` the object of your view from where you show/open the `popup window` than use `thread` to dismiss automatic the `popup window` when there is no click for defined time i.e. 10 seconds.

Here `mpopup` is the object of `PopupWindow`.

Use the below code for vanishing dialog window after time-out (i used 10 seconds).

Hope it will help you.

```
menu_bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.menu_popup, null); // inflating popup layout
                mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 400,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true); // Creation of popup
                mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
                mpopup.showAsDropDown(menu_bt, 50, -10);
                Button btnOk = (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.home);

                btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mpopup.dismiss(); // dismissing the popup with button click
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        // automatic dismissing the popup after 10 seconds
                                        mpopup.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Your problem solved???
If the answer is useful for you...than accept it ;)